# How to add IActionResultExecutor services like IActionResultExecutor<NotFoundResult> to endpoint-based routing app?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

How to add `IActionResultExecutor` services, which are available to controller-actions such as `IActionResultExecutor<NotFoundResult>`, to endpoint-based routing app?

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app, it's not a regular controller-action-based app but a custom one via [`app.UseEndpoints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutingapplicationbuilderextensions.useendpoints):
https://github.com/zwcloud/NancyFxViaAspNetCore/blob/646f9d820369d8fc78cf0c1f2cb18307e1851081/Nancy/NancyModule.cs#L176

And it threw an exception in my implementation inside [`endpoints.Map`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.map?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions_Map_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Routing_IEndpointRouteBuilder_System_String_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_RequestDelegate_):

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionResultExecutor`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundResult]' has been registered.'

```cs
public static Task WriteActionResult<TResult>(HttpContext context, TResult result) where TResult : IActionResult
{
    var executor = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionResultExecutor<TResult>>();
    //**exception thrown here** System.InvalidOperationException
    if (executor == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"No action result executor for {typeof(TResult).FullName} registered.");
    }
    var routeData = context.GetRouteData() ?? new RouteData();
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(context, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());
    return executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, result);
}

public dynamic GetResult()//main logic is written here
{
    //other logic omitted
    return new NotFoundResult();
}

//this function is called in Startup.Configure()
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseEndpoints((endpoints) =>
    {
        endpoints.Map(route, async context =>
        {
            dynamic result = GetResult(context);
            await WriteActionResult(context, result);
        });
    });
}
```

So I want to add `IActionResultExecutor<StatusCodeResult>`, `IActionResultExecutor<NotFoundResult>` and many other action result executors, which are available in controller actions, to the services in `Startup.ConfigureServices`.

I have already added MvcCore and Mvc in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddMvcCore();
    services.AddMvc()
    //...
}
```

But I don't know which class and assembly contains this type. And no documentation points out that.

Failed attempts I have made:

- Failed to find in the source code of ASP.NET Core but got nothing but the definition of `NotFoundResult`, etc.
- tried

  ```
  services.TryAddSingleton(typeof(IActionResultExecutor<StatusCodeResult>));
  ```

  But it threw an exception when `HostBuilder.Build()` in `Main`:

  ```
  System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type
  'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionResultExecutor`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult]'
  for service type
  'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionResultExecutor`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult]'.'
  ```

  [image: exception]
- tried

  ```cs
  services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IActionResultExecutor<NotFoundResult>),
      typeof(IActionResultExecutor<NotFoundResult>)));
  ```

  But it threw an exception when `HostBuilder.Build()` in `Main`:
  [image: exception]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out.

```
public static Task WriteActionResult(HttpContext context, NotFoundResult result)
{
   context.Response.StatusCode = result.StatusCode;
   return context.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
}
```

For `StatusCodeResult` like `NotFoundResult`, we shouldn't query a `IActionResultExecutor` but write to Response directly.

Learned from [WebApiContrib.Core](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib.Core)'s [implementation](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib.Core/blob/cfb6deeb0b2c132362597b2362232b5592f1ca1a/src/WebApiContrib.Core/Results/HttpContextExtensions.cs#L37).

Comment: I see you went the direction here of crafting the response. The docs make it sound like getting the executor from services of type IActionResultExecutor is the way to go. When you run the ExecuteAsync on the executor that basically does the same thing as writing the context response. Were you ever able to get the IActionResultExecutor implementation to work? I also get the exception that the service isn't registered, but I don't see how to wire it into DI.

Answer (score 0):

@zwcloud I ended up getting it working. I got stuck where you did then went through MS source code for MVC to see how they do it for ObjectResult types. You have to build a customActionResultExecutor class that implements your customActionResult. The executor class is what gets registered as a singleton with DI.

[Example Executor](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/04ce6cae44fb0cb11470c21769d41e3f8088e8aa/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Infrastructure/ObjectResultExecutor.cs)

[Example Singleton DI registration for the executor](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/04ce6cae44fb0cb11470c21769d41e3f8088e8aa/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)